# How to make app icon position fixed in a springboard programmatically

Tags: iphone, xcode5

How do i make app icon position on right top corner side on springboard programmatically by xcode5?

Answer (score 1):

This is **not** Possible, iOS will maintain it.

You can not set your app icon Programatically .

Comment: So, it is not possible to group app icon list programmatically?

Comment: No, it is not possible.

Comment: Viruss mca may be you are wrong. I could group my apps in my spring board according to genres (e.g.games, lifestyle). Though it is working on Jaikbroken iPhone. But it works. So may be it is possible to fix the position of an app in the spring board.

Comment: No, i guess we can not to fix app icon position, and for grouping when you drag app to any other app it will create group, and group title is given according its generes.

Comment: I know that. I want to do the grouping programmatically. As I can group my apps programmatically then it would be possible to fix the position of an app programmatically until the user tries to manually change the position.